# How do I cancel a coroutine run inside a withContext?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines, withcontext

I have a Repository defined as the following.

```
class StoryRepository {
    private val firestore = Firebase.firestore

    suspend fun fetchStories(): QuerySnapshot? {
        return try {
            firestore
                .collection("stories")
                .get()
                .await()
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            Log.e("StoryRepository", "Error in fetching Firestore stories: $e")
            null
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a ViewModel like this.

```
class HomeViewModel(
    application: Application
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private var viewModelJob = Job()
    private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)
    private val storyRepository = StoryRepository()

    private var _stories = MutableLiveData<List<Story>>()
    val stories: LiveData<List<Story>>
        get() = _stories

    init {
        uiScope.launch {
            getStories()
        }
        uiScope.launch {
            getMetadata()
        }            
    }

    private suspend fun getStories() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val snapshots = storyRepository.fetchStories()
            // Is this correct?
            if (snapshots == null) {
                cancel(CancellationException("Task is null; local DB not refreshed"))
                return@withContext
            }
            val networkStories = snapshots.toObjects(NetworkStory::class.java)
            val stories = NetworkStoryContainer(networkStories).asDomainModel()
            _stories.postValue(stories)
        }
    }

    suspend fun getMetadata() {
        // Does some other fetching
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        viewModelJob.cancel()
    }
}
```

As you can see, sometimes, `StoryRepository().fetchStories()` may fail and return `null`. If the return value is `null`, I would like to not continue what follows after the checking for `snapshots` being `null` block. Therefore, I would like to cancel that particular coroutine (the one that runs `getStories()` without cancelling the other coroutine (the one that runs `getMetadata()`). How do I achieve this and is `return`-ing from `withContext` a bad-practice?

Comment: Seems correct as of https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/idiomatic-way-to-cancel-coroutine-from-within-a-suspend-function/5268

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Is it okay to `return` from `withContext` and should I provide a mechanism to catch the `CancellationException`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your approach is right, you can always make some improvements to make it simpler or more idiomatic (especially when you're not pleased with your own code).

These are just some suggestions that you may want to take into account:

You can make use of Kotlin Scope Functions, or more specifically the `let` function like this:

```
private suspend fun getStories() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    storyRepository.fetchStories()?.let { snapshots ->
        val networkStories = snapshots.toObjects(NetworkStory::class.java)
        NetworkStoryContainer(networkStories).asDomainModel()
    } ?: throw CancellationException("Task is null; local DB not refreshed")
}
```

This way you'll be returning your data or throwing a `CancellationException` if `null`.

When you're working with coroutines inside a ViewModel you have a CoroutineScope ready to be used if you add this dependendy to your gradle file:

```
androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:{version}
```

So you can use `viewModelScope` to build your coroutines, which will run on the main thread:

```
init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _stories.value = getStories()
    }

    viewModelScope.launch {
        getMetadata()
    }
}
```

You can forget about cancelling its `Job` during `onCleared` since `viewModelScope` is lifecycle-aware.

Now all you have left to do is handling the exception with a `try-catch` block or with the  `invokeOnCompletion` function applied on the `Job` returned by the `launch` builder.

Comment: If I wanted to catch the `CancellationException`, how do I achieve that with your code? Shall I wrap the entirety of `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` block with a `try catch` block?

Comment: @Richard It would be easier if you wrap its call with a `try-catch` block inside the `launch` builder. Or you can use the `invokeOnCompletion` function that the `Job` has. Its throwable would not be `null`, that's how you know something went wrong.

Comment: I see, would it be something like the following: `viewModelScope.launch { _stories.value = getStories) }.invokeOnCompletion { cause -> catch(cause: CancellationException) { ... } }`?

Comment: @Richard More like: `.invokeOnCompletion { cause -> cause?.apply {...}}`. The thing is `cause` won't be `null` if there was a problem. You can do anything you want inside the `apply` block or whatever you use.

Comment: I think you meant *cause will be `null` if there isn't any problem*? Can you catch an exception inside an `apply` block?

Comment: @Richard You're not catching it inside, you're working with it inside. `cause` is the exception.